# Saving a random choice and using it later

Tags: python, random

I have got my program to select a random choice from a list like so:

```
from random import choice
solider_long = ['1', '2', '3']
from random import choice
solider_speed = [ '4', '5', '6']
from random import choice 
solider_block = [ '4', '5', '6']          
print ("You choose solider")
print ("Your stats: close combat : " + choice(solider_close))
print ("            long range combat : " + choice(solider_long))
print ("            long range combat : " + choice(solider_speed))
print ("            long range combat : " + choice(solider_block))
print ("Press Y to continue")
```

I want the program to remember it's random choice so I can use the number it choice later on in the program. How can this be done?

Comment: You probably want to restructure the entire thing to use an object and separate the logic from the display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to import once. You can save your `choice()` to variable that you can use at a later point.

```
from random import choice


solider_long = ['1', '2', '3']

solider_speed = [ '4', '5', '6']

solider_block = [ '4', '5', '6']

# save the choices in a variable
choice_solider_close = choice(solider_close)
choice_solider_long = choice(solider_long)
choice_solider_speed = choice(solider_speed)
choice_solider_block = choice(solider_block)

print ("You choose solider")
print ("Your stats: close combat : " + choice_solider_close)
print ("            long range combat : " + choice_solider_long)
print ("            long range combat : " + choice_solider_speed)
print ("            long range combat : " + choice_solider_block)
print ("Press Y to continue")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your imports after the first one serve no purpose, get rid of them.

Once you've done that, the solution is simple:

```
c1 = choice(soldier_close)
c2 = choice(soldier_long)
c3 = choice(soldier_speed)
c4 = choice(soldier_block)
```

If you're not familiar with the concept of variables, consider reading a Python tutorial, such as the official one: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/.